# Kindo grid filter on decimal values defaulting to two decimal places

Tags: telerik-grid

I have a Telerik-Kindo Grid in which one of the columns is a number with four decimal places. When I am trying to filter in that column, it is accepting four decimal places in the filter text field but while actually filtering, the in-built filter function is considering on the first two decimal places. I know this for sure because, when I click on the filter button associated with the column after filtering, the text field displays the number I entered with just two decimal places. My other two decimal values are taken off.

Is there any way that I can make the filter function of the Telerik-Kindo Grid to consider all of my 4 decimal values for filtering?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution for this.
This is what you put in the MVC wrapper

```
.Filterable(filterable => filterable.UI("customNumericFilter"))
```

And implementation of that in your Java Script

```
 function customNumericFilter (element) {
    element.kendoNumericTextBox({
        format: "n5",
        decimals: 5
    });
}
```